# Where to put API Code?

Tags: api

I want to use some of the Wordpress API built in functions such as wp_remote_request(). I have tried using this in a php file in my root Wordpress installation but I am just getting an error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_remote_request() in
>   /home/pacekuwa/public_html/gf.php on line 23

I have a feeling I am not putting my code in the right place or need to include one or more Wordpress files...

Could anyone tell me where I should be putting my code?

EDIT:

I am trying to create a page that makes a remote API call to my Gravity Forms plugin to retrieve submitted form entries using the Gravity Forms Web API. I was trying to follow their [example](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/web-api/#get-entries), but don't know where the code they give should go within my installation to get it to work.

Comment: Why you are using WordPress function in a separate file ?

Comment: Hi Sumit, can you tell me what file I should put the code in, in my Wordpress installation?

Comment: It's depends on what you are posting ? Please edit your question and describe what you are trying to do with `wp_remote_request`

Comment: @Sumit - I have added a further explanation to my quiestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [create a plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) to contain your code. The [`admin_post_` action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_(action)) can be used to trigger a request handler. WordPress core will be loaded, and the API will work.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Ben's GF Plugin
*/

// for logged-in users
add_action( 'admin_post_ben_gf', 'ben_gf_handle_request' );
// for non logged-in users
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_ben_gf', 'ben_gf_handle_request' );

function ben_gf_handle_request() {

    // Your processing code.
    // WordPress functions will work here.
    echo 'Your home url: ' . home_url();

    // die() at the end to terminate execution
    die();
}
```

This will map your request handler to the URL:

```
http://www.example.com/wp-admin/admin-post.php?action=ben_gf
```

Use caution if you are allowing non-logged in users to access this URL, you don't want to publicly expose sensitive data.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is a very helpful explanation, and much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress functions are used in theme or plugin files. If you want to use wordpress functions in custom php file you have to include wp-load.php file. `require_once("../../../../wp-load.php");` . Number of dots depends where is your custom file.